# how to import react library from express app in nx/nrwl

Tags: webpack, nrwl-nx, nrwl

I'm using [`nx`](https://nx.dev/) to manage my monorepo, and I have an express app with adminjs, which requires react components.

When I try to import a react component to this app, from my libraries, I get:

```
'@nx/admin-ui-components' is imported by apps/admin-ui/src/TestInner.ts, but could not be resolved – treating it as an external dependency
```

There's no issue with the library itself, it works on other apps.

Any ideas?

```
$ npx nx report
npx nx report

 >  NX   Report complete - copy this into the issue template

   Node : 17.6.0
   OS   : darwin arm64
   yarn : 1.22.18

   nx : 14.4.3
   @nrwl/angular : Not Found
   @nrwl/cypress : 14.4.3
   @nrwl/detox : Not Found
   @nrwl/devkit : 14.4.3
   @nrwl/eslint-plugin-nx : 14.4.3
   @nrwl/express : 14.4.3
   @nrwl/jest : 14.4.3
   @nrwl/js : 14.4.3
   @nrwl/linter : 14.4.3
   @nrwl/nest : Not Found
   @nrwl/next : Not Found
   @nrwl/node : 14.4.3
   @nrwl/nx-cloud : 14.2.0
   @nrwl/nx-plugin : Not Found
   @nrwl/react : 14.4.3
   @nrwl/react-native : Not Found
   @nrwl/schematics : Not Found
   @nrwl/storybook : 14.4.3
   @nrwl/web : 14.4.3
   @nrwl/workspace : 14.4.3
   typescript : 4.7.4
   ---------------------------------------
   Community plugins:
```

Answer (score 0):

So the problem is I was telling `adminjs` to bundle the file, and it uses rollup under the hood, which of course doesn't know about `nx`.

So the solution is to import to component in "nx land" and inject it to `adminjs`

```
import ToolEditor from "./ToolEditor"

// @ts-ignore
AdminJS.UserComponents = AdminJS.UserComponents || {}
// @ts-ignore
AdminJS.UserComponents["ToolEditor"] = ToolEditor

// and then in adminjs options
{
...
component: AdminJS.bundle("ToolEditor"),
}
```